# How to read local.properties android in java files

Tags: java, android, properties

I want to add custom fields in `local.properties` like

```
debug.username=test123
debug.password=abcd1234
```

can add `.properties` files in assets folder and read that easily.

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();
Properties properties = null;        
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(fileName);
properties = new Properties();
properties.load(inputStream);
```

But don't want to do this.
As i want every team member of our to use `local.properties` to specify there custom attribute. which is not the part of version control system.

So how to **read `local.properties` placed in the root folder of gradle based android project in java files at runtime**?

Answer (score 17):

I know that this is an old question but I recently encountered the same thing and I thought I'd share my solution:

1. Set the value in your **local.properties** file.
2. Read the value in your Gradle build script and set it to a `BuildConfig` constant.
3. Access the `BuildConfig` constant in your Java code.

**local.properties**

```
username=myUsername
```

**build.gradle**:

```
def getUsername() {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    return properties.getProperty("username");
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "USERNAME", "\""+getUsername()+"\""
    }
}
```

Example Java class:

```
package your.package.name;

class MyClass {
    String getUsername() {
        return BuildConfig.USERNAME; // Will return "myUsername"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kat can you be more specific? You should be able to move the `buildConfigField` declaration from `defaultConfig` to one of your `buildTypes` or `productFlavors`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = 
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fileName.properties");
properties.load(inputStream);
Username=properties.getProperty("username");      
password=properties.getProperty("password");
```

More detailed answer is here
http://pillsfromtheweb.blogspot.in/2014/09/properties-file-in-android.html

and for asset use this code

```
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open("fileName.properties");
            properties.load(inputStream);
            String Username = properties.getProperty("username");
            String password = properties.getProperty("password");
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("message: ",e.toString);
        }
```

Comment: Didnt work inputstream comes as null. Did you tried it yourself?

Comment: Its because your getResourceAsStream is returning null, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053059/getresourceasstream-is-returning-null-properties-file-is-not-loading

Comment: they are saying to put file under some directory. As i specified in the question i would like to avoid that and use local.properties of root folder.

Comment: For this to work i need to put the file in assets folder of root directory . But i needed to read file local.properties from root folder. I mentioned that in the question

Comment: InputStream input = new FileInputStream("/path/of/file/fileName.properties"); put the path of your properties file inside inverted comma's,

Comment: i can read asset folder files. Learning is to know how to read files from root directory. And standard is to use local.properties file for doing local build setttings stuff.

Comment: how can i know the path of android root directory of my app.?

Comment: "/system/app/" + localApplicationInfo.packageName

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant of the other solutions, stripped down to the essentials:

local.properties:

```
username=test123
password=abcd1234
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        buildConfigField "String", "USERNAME", "\"" + properties.getProperty('username') + "\""
        buildConfigField "String", "PASSWORD", "\"" + properties.getProperty('password') + "\""
    }
}
```

Java:

```
String userName = BuildConfig.USERNAME;
```