# Local CMake configuration from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-studio-2.2

When using CMake in a regular project, some variables (e.g library paths) can be configured via `-D` option or by using `ccmake` or `cmake-gui` The values are saved in the cache, and this provides for a local configuration that is specific to every user/developer of the code.

In Android Studio, CMake can be configured from Gradle, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent to the options above. The `local.properties` file can be read from gradle, but it's overwritten by AS.

Is there any way of setting CMake variables to local values from Android Studio?

Example: On a regular CMake project, I can add a line to my CMakeLists.txt like:

`set(EIGEN_DIR /usr/local/include/eigen3 CACHE PATH "Eigen path")`

And then two different developers may set that value to their particular systems (ie. `/usr/local/include/eigen3` or `/opt/local/include/eigen3`) without affecting the project source code. However, in Android Studio, the only way seems to be from `build.gradle`, which is part of the project, and will get committed to the repositories.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.htm,  use format "-Dyour-cmake-variables=VALUE". this should be saved into build/.externalNativeBuild somewhere there

Comment: Those variables are not local. I'll add an example of the intended usage to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this can be achieved by putting the variables with the desired value in the `local.properties` file, and then read them with the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45754564/1762681):

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream(project.rootProject.file('local.properties')))
String conf_value = props['conf.value']
```

and then

```
externalNativeBuild{
     cmake {
          arguments "-DMY_CONF_VALUE="+conf_value
          ...
     }
}
```